# ether holding time for The DAO recursive calls vulnerability case

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, cryptocurrency

I saw a statement is that "28-day holding period under the terms of the Ethereum smart contract" explains the hacking case was solved because of this.

But I don't understand this holding period is coming from where.

Is it related to eth contract or is this a special case?

What I am also looking for is, to solving a scam, is there any holding period for any mainnet coin?

source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_DAO_(organization)